# Replacing characters only a set amount of time

Tags: php

I've been googling a bit, but I can't figure out what keywords to use.

I'm saving the users date of birth, and I want to make sure the format is YYYY-MM-DD.
I'm thinking something like:

```
if(!ctype_digit(str_replace("-", "", $dob)) || strlen(str_replace("-", "", $dob)) != 8)
{
   echo "Incorrect format: date of birth";
}
```

For this, I need to use strlen() to only replace three - chars. If it's more or less than 3, then echo incorrect format. How do I achieve this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered using `preg_replace()` yet? Or at least test `$dob`against a regular pattern.

Comment: Thanks, Starx gave me a working code. Voted up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using regex?

```
if ( !preg_match( "/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/", $dob) )
{ 
    echo "Invalid date.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To find many examples, search for "validating dates" or, in your case, to find php examples, try "php validate date format" -- you'll see most examples are solved with regular expressions, which is your ticket this this sort of thing.  Reg Expressions can help you validate dates, email address formats, inputs for passwords that meet minimal requirements (e.g. at least 8 characters, at least one numeric and one capital letter, etc.)

Here's one such example:

```
if(preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/',$date)){
   // good date
}else{
   // bad date
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also check that the date is an actual date; not just that it *looks* like an actual date.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/D", $dob))
{ 
    echo 'Invalid date';
}

else
{

    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $dob);

    if (!checkdate((int) $month, (int) $day, (int) $year))
    {
        echo 'Invalid date';
    }

}
```

You don't want to accept `1988-06-31` after all.